# How do I set up a nav to change font colors at certain points?

Tags: jquery, html, css

My site just has a basic horizontal nav bar at the top. The site is a long one page site with a different colored background at certain points. I was wanting to know how to change the font color from one color to another at certain points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a class to your links after the window has scrolled the amount you desire.

So you would set up your default color

```
a{color:red;}
```

and then a class for what you want to change

```
a.changeColor{color:green}
```

And then run a function on scroll (these are bad for performance)

```
$window = $(window),
$nav = $('.nav'),
scrollTop = $window.scrollTop();

$window.scroll(function(){
    scrollTop = $window.scrollTop();
  if(scrollTop > 500){
    $nav.children('a').addClass('changeColor');
  }else{
    $nav.children('a').removeClass();
  }
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hahrywa6/2/

I have edited this so you can target divs as well, this way you don't need to hardcode a value. This might be better for you.

To do this, create a variable that will target the div you want to change the text colour when your nav hits it.

```
var yourDiv = $('.yourDivName').offset().top;
```

Find its offset from the top.
Now just use the same scrollTop Variable against it in an if statement. If the window scroll is more than your element, you want to add the class.

```
var $window = $(window),
$nav = $('.nav'),
scrollTop = $window.scrollTop(),
triggerDiv = $('#trigger-div').offset().top;
$window.scroll(function(){
    scrollTop = $window.scrollTop();
  if(scrollTop > 500){
    $nav.children('a').removeClass().addClass('changeColor');
  }else{
    $nav.children('a').removeClass();
  }
  if(scrollTop > triggerDiv){
    $nav.children('a').removeClass().addClass('changeColor2');
  }
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hahrywa6/2/

Comment: So I can't seem to get either methods to work for me, either with a div(Which is what I would prefer) or a hardcoded value. I haven't used jsfiddle before but I think I uploaded everything correctly. https://jsfiddle.net/Remirlis/Lt7o6Lyd/

Comment: Couple things: Your javascript panel was set to pure JS, this is using jquery! I've changed "children" to "find". children checks your elements immediate children, ie one level down. Find will check all the contents inside of nav. here is updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lt7o6Lyd/1/

Comment: Thanks! That did it for me.